# CArrayDataProvider display empty values

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a problem with CArrayDataProvider apparently returning empty value. 
When I type the SQL (see below),  on mysql,  I get 7 records,  my view displays 7 lines but with empty values.

Here is the necessary code, if you need more, please ask me.

**actionIndex of the Post Controller**

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
        $user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM post 
                LEFT JOIN comment ON post.id = comment.post_id
                AND comment.user_id =:user_id
                LIMIT 0 , 30 ';
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $rawData = $command->queryAll();

        $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
                    'id'=>'post',
                    'sort'=>array(
                    'defaultOrder' => 'post.created',
                    ),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>10,
                    ),
        ));

$this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'category_id'=>$category_id,
        ));
    }
```

**view Index**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

**and view _view**

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode(Post::model()->subject); ?>
```

Is anyone can see where the problem comes from?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your **_view.php** instead of whatever you are doing:

```
<?= CHtml::encode($data['subject']); ?>
```

If it still fails, check to see if the `$dataProvider` actually has records:

```
<?php var_dump($dataProvider->data); ?>
```